# How to avoid drop down closing after i clicked the drop down, actually i want to read the drop down values

Tags: java, selenium

I have to read the drop-down values in the bootstrap dropdown while automating if I click on the drop-down menu, it's opened and closing, so the drop-down values are not matching with my XPath, if
the drop-down is in open, then only my XPath identifies those elements.

so I want to avoid the drop-down closing, to read the drop-down values, how can we achieve?

Comment: Can you please post the HTML for the dropdown, and the Java code you are already using to try and make this work?

Comment: Debug your code to find out if click on another element does not resolve with click to the dropdown. You can also try to invoke the click by Action where you can include moving to target element. Or try to click via javascript (JavascriptExecutor).

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Xpath for this dropdown is "//button[@id='dropdownMenuButton']/../div". Like this you can try on your application.

If you still have issues, can you share the HTML part of the dropdown.